# Ng-minlength not working with custom validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm working with angularJS, i'm trying to do a form where user type his username and application validate if it's available on database and his length is between 5/10 chars.

```
<input type="text" name="uname" ng-model="user.uname"
ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="10" uniqueusername required/>
```

Uniqueusername is a directive that check if username is available:

```
app.directive('uniqueusername', function($http){
return{
    require : 'ngModel',
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function(scope,elem,attrs,ctrl){
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
            $http.get('/api/check'+value).success(function(data,status){
                if(data.available=='true'){
                    ctrl.$setValidity('unique',true);
                }
                else{
                    ctrl.$setValidity('unique',false);
.........................................................................
```

When i type an username with less than 5 chars, is valid. And this shouldn't happen.
If I delete uniqueusername for input it work perfectly.

Thank for your answers.

Comment: could you post the complete uniqueusername directive?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? Angular JS 1.3 has a new feature that supports asynchronous validation on the server. Your problem is likely that the regular validation code does not wait for your .success callback to happen.

Comment: @SunilD. I'm using 1.2.23, i'll try change to 1.3.

Comment: @MajoB Directive is complete, i only have omitted the finals '}'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to return a value from the parser function:

```
app.directive('uniqueusername', function($http){
    return{
        require : 'ngModel',
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope,elem,attrs,ctrl){
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                $http.get('/api/check'+value).success(function(data,status){
                    if(data.available=='true'){
                        ctrl.$setValidity('unique',true);
                    }
                    else{
                        ctrl.$setValidity('unique',false);
                    }
                }
                return value;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right. I had forgot return value.